# CS50 Project 1 Search bar Question: How do I make the search bar filter through the entries to find the possible ones and display them in a list?

Tags: python, django, django-views, cs50, searchbar

I am working on CS50 Project 1 to make a search bar that searches through the possible wikipedia-like entries using Django. If you type in the exact name of the title, you will be redirected to that entry page. If the exact name of the entry is not searched, how do I display a list of possible entries using the query?

views.search

```
def search(request):
    entry_list = util.list_entries()
    query = request.GET.get("q", "")
    if query in entry_list:
        return redirect(get_entry, query)
    else:
        results = []
        for entry in entry_list:
            if query in entry:
                results.append(entry)
        return render(request, "encyclopedia/index.html", {
            "entry": results
            })
```

index.html

```
{% extends "encyclopedia/layout.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Encyclopedia
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
    <h1>All Pages</h1>

    <ul>
        {% for entry in entries %}
            <a href = "wiki/{{ entry }}"><li>{{ entry }}</li></a>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>

{% endblock %}
```

If anything but the exact title is searched for, the user receives a blank page. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. To anyone else who is struggling with this part of Project 1:

views.search

```py
def search(request):
    entry_list = util.list_entries()
    query = request.GET.get("q", "")
    if query in entry_list:
        return redirect(get_entry, query)
    else:
        results = [entry for entry in entry_list if query.lower() in entry.lower()]
        return render(request, "encyclopedia/index.html", {
            "entries": results
            })
```

You have to create a list to store the possible results and search through the entries using a for loop and the in keyword.